How to solve CORS errors generated by httplib in the same LAN
I created two VMs on vmware, one is with ip address 192.168.247.129 running httplib server and the other is client with ip address 192.168.247.146.
The two virtual machines can ping each other
The server side code is this:
void
runServer (const std::string &filePath)
{
  Server svr;

  svr.Get ("/get_stats", [filePath] (const Request &, Response &res) {
    std::ifstream t (filePath);
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << t.rdbuf ();
    std::string fileContents = buffer.str ();

    res.set_header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.set_content (fileContents, "application/json");
  });

  svr.Post("/set_config", [](const Request &req, Response &res) {
    try {
        auto jsonData = ordered_json::parse(req.body);

        // 打印从前端接收到的数据
        std::cout << "Received configuration: " << jsonData.dump(4) << std::endl;

        simConfig.numNodes = jsonData.at("numNodes").get<uint32_t>();
        simConfig.totalTime = jsonData.at("totalTime").get<double>();
        simConfig.source = jsonData.at("source").get<uint32_t>();
        simConfig.destination = jsonData.at("destination").get<uint32_t>();
        simConfig.dataRate = jsonData.at("dataRate").get<std::string>();
        simConfig.packetSize = jsonData.at("packetSize").get<uint32_t>();
        simConfig.appStartTime = jsonData.at("appStartTime").get<double>();
        simConfig.appStopTime = jsonData.at("appStopTime").get<double>();

        res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.set_content("{\"status\": \"configuration received\"}", "application/json");

        // Notify simulation thread to start simulation
        {
          std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(jsonMutex);
          configReceived = true;
          jsonCv.notify_one();
        }
      } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Error parsing JSON: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.set_content("{\"error\": \"Invalid JSON data\"}", "application/json");
        res.status = 400;
      }
  });

  std::cout << "Server started at http://localhost:7979" << std::endl;
  svr.listen ("0.0.0.0", 7979); // 在端口 7979 上监听
}

The client code is this:
const sendEntityValuesToBackend = (entityValues: string []) =>{
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'http://192.168.247.129:7979/set_config';
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        if(xhr.status === 200){
          console.log("后端响应:", xhr.responseText);
        }else{
          console.error("配置网络时出错:", xhr.statusText);
        }
      }
    };

    const jsonData ={
      numNodes: 20,
      totalTiam: 100.0,
      source: 0,
      destination: 6,
      dataRate: "30kbps",
      packetSize: 1024,
      appStartTIme: 0.0,
      appStopTime: 100.0
    };

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({jsonData}));
  }

But the client still reports an error:
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.247.129:7979/set_config' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
POST http://192.168.247.129:7979/set_config net::ERR_FAILED 500 (Internal Server Error)
I have no other options, please help me.
Thanks!
I asked chatgpt, and chatgpt said it was an error caused by CORS, but I followed chatgpt's advice and added:
res.set_header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
But the error still exists.
